# Migrating a PositiveSmallIntegerField to a PositiveIntegerField and using the BIGINT field in Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-south, django-models

One of my models had a field defined a `PositiveSmallIntegerField`. Upon describing the table, I've seen that it has been defined as an `INTEGER`.

I'd like to store values of larger range and therefore I've modified my model to use the `PositiveIntegerField`.

Now when I run South to generate migrations, it says that nothing was changed in the model? I can see my changes clearly but South ignored this. Why?

Will using a `PositiveIntegerField` use the `BIGINT` field in Postgres? Does Django support the `BIGINT` field of Postgres?

Comment: You could always `ALTER TABLE thetable ALTER COLUMN thecol TYPE bigint;`

Comment: @CraigRinger, yes, that's true but is it the correct approach? If nothing else, I will have to resort to this method though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use django's built-in `BigIntegerField` instead of `PositiveIntegerField`.

If South still ignores this change, you can create an [empty migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#schemamigration) and add the following to your `forwards` method:

```
db.alter_column('table_name', 'column', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.BigIntegerField'))
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I should've read the the docs more thoroughly. I didn't even know that a `BigIntegerField` existed. I'd give you another +1 if I could.